# GCP linux startup script to grant all users permission to directory and files

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, startup, startupscript

I am attempting to run the following startup script on a GCP vm instance:

```
mkdir /home/example_user/
mkdir /home/example_user/test
echo "hello world" >> /home/example_user/test/.env
chmod 777 /home/example_user/
```

When I login to the created vm, and the startup script has finished running. I try to confirm the permissions were set properly via:

```
nano /home/example_user/test/.env
```

> Permission denied

I would like that an user that logins via ssh does not need to prefix `sudo` with there commands, or enter root via `sudo su` prior to

```
nano /home/example_user/test/.env
```

I have tried

```
chmod 777 /home/example_user/
chmod a+x /home/example_user/
chmod -R a+x /home/example_user/
```

How do I properly give access permissions to all users on the vm instance within the startup script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change permissions of the folder and its children recursively:

```
chmod -R 777 /home/example_user/
```

However, there are better strategies. Linux implements the concept of groups. Add the users that should have access to a shared folder to the same group. Then set the folder's group and the permissions for that group.

[How to Manage Users with Groups in Linux](https://www.linux.com/topic/desktop/how-manage-users-groups-linux/)